# The zero case in separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Introduction:** When solving a separable ODE, There is a subtle problem that seems no be neglected. And that is the $y=0$ at some point case. According to my understanding you divide to 2 cases - $y\equiv0$ (everywhere) and $y\neq0$ (ever). But these 2 exclude the possibility of $y=0$ at some points. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the general argument here.

**Example** (from my professor's notes)**:**
solve $y'=3y^{\frac{2}{3}}$. 
**(Fake) Answer:**
$y\equiv0$ is a valid solution. else we can divide and get $\frac{dy}{dx}=3y^{\frac{2}{3}}\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{3y^{\frac{2}{3}}}=dx\Rightarrow\int\frac{dy}{3y^{\frac{2}{3}}}=\int dx\Rightarrow y^{\frac{1}{3}}=x+c\Rightarrow y=(x+c)^{3}$ so these are the only 2 solutions.
**However**, note that for example
 $y(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & x\leq -c\\
(x+c)^{3} & x\geq -c
\end{cases}$  
is a valid solution as well. (basically what happened is we proved the solution only locally)
**My question** is how do we make sure that in general we don't miss any annoying cases like this?

Comment: You are right and the function you mentioned in the example is also a solution. So here $y\equiv 0$ is so called [singular solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution). At any its point $x_0$ it and $y=(x-x_0)^3$ have equal derivatives